# Convex hull and open balls that are contained in / contain it

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the affine subspace in the $n$ dimensional Euclidean space defined by $\sum_1^n x_k=1$.

Then the standard basis elements $e_1, ..., e_n$ are contained in $P$. Now, let $T \subset P$ be the convex hull of the points $e_1, ... e_n$. If the metric is the usual Euclidean distance, what is the radius of the smallest ball in $P$ that contains $T$ and what is the radius of the largest ball in $P$ that is contained in $T$?

This problem comes out from a linear algebra exam...and at least fortunately I know the notion of the convex hull and relative topology. But this problem just overwhelms me...I cannot find a way to approach. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $T$ is a regular $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex. Conveniently it
is highly symmetric. You are asking for the circumradius and inradius.
Like triangles, simplices have circumcentres and incentres. But due to
the symmetry these centres are the same, viz., $\frac1n(e_1+\cdots+e_n)$.

The circumradius is the distance from the centre to any vertex, say $e_1$,
and the inradius is the distance from the centre to any face of the simplex,
for example, the intersection of the hyperplanes $x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$
and $x_1=0$. I'll leave the calculation of these distances to you.